# Why MySql query update with guid don't affect rows?

Tags: sql, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have a MySql query update:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://oldcomain.com/', 'http://mynewcdndomain.com/') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

I'm using it on wordpress domain, inside amazon rds database, i'm updating it via MySQL Workbench and get there results:

> 0row(s) affected Rows matched: 24103 Changed: 0 Warning: 0

As you can see it finds rows that i need, but it does not update, i'm trying update all my wordpress media that is on wordpress to my cdn amazon s3 url.

Update:
Also tried:

> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,
>   'olddocmain.com', 'newcdndomain.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';

Doesn't work ether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you get from workBench shows that it can find the matched records for the attachment, but then for guid attribute, no rows include 'oldcomain.com/', so that's why it's changing nothing.

The query you are using is correct. I think maybe verify the matching characters again, e.g. 'oldcomain.com' instead of 'oldcomain.com/'.

Or you can try wildcard characters, like try to put % before and after matching characters, '%oldcomain.com%'.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content ='newcdndomain.com' 
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND
      post_content ='olddocmain.com';
```